# MySQL max-value – when and how often

Tags: mysql, performance, max

If I have a query like

```
SELECT (MAX(b.A)/a.A) AS c
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON a.b_id = b.id
GROUP by a.id
```

does MySQL evaluate the value for "MAX(b.A)" for every row or only once?

It's just of interest to me if there is room for performance improvement or not.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

OK let's move on to a real world example: I want to calculate the proportional value of a users likes compared to max-user-likes.

The query to only read the max value of users.likes (which is indexed) takes 0.0003

```
SELECT MAX(likes) 
FROM users
```

So I now know the value of max-user-likes, let's say it's 10000 so I could query like this which takes 0.0007s:

```
SELECT (users.likes/10000) AS weight 
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users ON posts.author_id = users.id
```

So one would expect to have both queries together to be something like 0.0003 + 0.0007s, but it takes 0.3s:

```
SELECT (users.likes/(SELECT MAX(likes) FROM users)) AS weight 
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users ON posts.author_id = users.id
```

So something seems still wrong with my database - any suggestions?

Comment: If the column A in the 'b' table has an index, nothing will have to be calculated since index would be sorted. For a case where there is no index, I would imagine the optimizer is smart enough to compute the max value just once.

Comment: That's making perfect sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the expression within an aggregation function is evaluated and checked for NULL for each row. There certainly can be a optimization for `MIN` and `MAX` in case of walking through an index, but I doubt that.

BTW, you can easily check this, when you execute `MAX(id)` on a large table. You will see that the execution time is the same as for `COUNT(id)` (and might be much more than `COUNT(*)` depending on the engine).

Answer (score 3):

Since you have no `GROUP BY` clause, the result will only have one row and you can't know from which row the value of `a.A` will be. The value of `MAX(b.A)` will be only evaluated once.

When you have a `GROUP BY` clause, `MAX(b.A)` will be evaluated for every **group**.

Comment: you are right, I forgot the group by in my example - edited it. That would not be good if you are right and it's evaluated for every group!?

Comment: Why would that not be good? Actually your question doesn't make much sense to me. The `GROUP BY` and with that the `MAX()` gets applied after the tables have been filtered with `WHERE` clause. In this result set MySQL looks for rows which have identical `a.id` and from this group the row with `MAX(b.A)` gets displayed. So MySQL "touches" every row, either by the row value itself or through index. That's how it works. But I don't get, why this is such a big deal for you.

Comment: added a better example @tombom maybe you can help?

Comment: @RaphaelJeger When you look at the `EXPLAIN` of your updated query, you will most likely see "Select tables optimized away" in it, which means that the subquery will only be executed once. But it may well be, that the index will be used for the subquery, but not for the main query, since you're selecting from the same table in sub and main. In earlier versions and under certain circumstances MySQL can use an index only once per table (and query).